# Integration the API with JackBe Presto Platform

Tags: rest-api

I'm integrating Salesforce API with JackBe Presto platform using WSDL,
when i call the Login method gives me the error, "INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token, or user locked out."
I checked the credentials that do the login and are correct, and the Password I add the "Security Token" but I still throwing that error.
I checked the login attempt and shows me Invalid Login,
The request to salesforce is correct but can not be authenticated

The account I do the login is a "Developer Edition"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the login attempt in Salesforce? If you go to Setup | Manage Users | Users |  and scroll to the bottom then there is a section which shows you all failed and successful login attempts.
If you don't see any record there, then your call is not reaching Salesforce (or not reaching the correct instance).
If there is a record there then it should indicate the problem.
If the user is locked (which happens after too many failed attempts), then there will be a button at the top of the page to Unlock the account.

Comment: In Login Attempt if the record shows but says Invalid Login.
I used SoapUI and Apex Data Loader and if I can do successfully login to the Salesforce API